# How to handle two nested .map() to return Some or None?

Tags: rust

I cannot understand how to make this code work:

```rust
pub fn convert_player(
    id: String,
    created_at: OffsetDateTime,
    //...
    coach_id: Option<String>,
    coach: Option<Box<DomainCoach>>,
) -> Self {}

Player::convert_player(
    o.id.to_owned(),
    o.created_at,
    //...
    o.coach_id.as_ref().map(|id| { // o.coach_id can be None
        self.coach_hashmap
            .get(id) // this can be None
            .map(|_| Box::new(self.convert_coach(id)))
    })
)
```

error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    |
259 |           Player::convert_player(
    |           -------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
296 | /             o.coach_id.as_ref().map(|id| {
297 | |                     .map(|_| Box::new(self.convert_coach(id)))
298 | |             }),
    | |______________^ expected `Option<Box<Coach>>`, found `Option<Option<Box<...>>>`
    |
    = note: expected enum `Option<Box<_>>`
               found enum `Option<Option<Box<_>>>`
note: associated function defined here
    |
355 |     pub fn convert(
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
375 |         convert_coach: Option<Box<Coach>>,
    |         ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: See the [`Option::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.flatten) method. Like `o.coach_id.as_ref().map(...).flatten()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) instead of `map` when the called closure may return `None`:

```
o.coach_id.as_ref().and_then(|id| { // o.coach_id can be None
    self.coach_hashmap
        .get(id) // this can be None
        .map(|_| Box::new(self.convert_coach(id)))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Option::flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.flatten):

> Converts from `Option<Option<T>>` to `Option<T>`.

```
        self.coach_hashmap
            .get(id) // this can be None
            .map(|_| Box::new(self.convert_coach(id)))
            .flatten()
```

Comment: Good point, `and_then()` is one less function call, and expresses the intent more clearly.